# Add images with text in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I am creating a select tag drop down with countries name as option and i want to add the respected countries flag with them:
I used this HTML

```
    <div class="form-group" id="abc">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Language: </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="select2me form-control" name = "locale" id="select_lang">
            @foreach($languages as $lang)
                <option value="{{$lang->locale}}" @if($lang->locale == $company->locale) selected="selected" @endif>{{$lang->language}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT USED:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          $.fn.select2.defaults.set("theme", "bootstrap");
          $('.select2me').select2({
             placeholder: "Select",
             width: '100%',
             allowClear: false
           });
     function format(state) {
                if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
                return "<img class='flag' src='" + MyFILEPATH() + "flags/" + state.id.toLowerCase() + ".png'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + state.text;
            }
            $("#select_lang").select2({
                placeholder: "Select a Country",
                allowClear: true,
                formatResult: format,
                formatSelection: format,
                escapeMarkup: function (m) {
                    return m;
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Tried this and this is working fine:

```
$("#select_lang").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a Country",
    allowClear: true,
    templateResult: format,
    templateSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function (m) {
    return m;
  }
});
```

Please try use templateResult and templateSelection instead of formatResult and formatSelection