# Yii2 Kartik Select2 - Template to formatting each list element

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

i'm looking to Kartik Select2 Page

In particular i want to add an image to each element of the list like the example:

```
use kartik\widgets\Select2;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

// Templating example of formatting each list element
$url = \Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/images/flags/';
$format = <<< SCRIPT
function format(state) {
    if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
    src = '$url' +  state.id.toLowerCase() + '.png'
    return '<img class="flag" src="' + src + '"/>' + state.text;
}
SCRIPT;
$escape = new JsExpression("function(m) { return m; }");
$this->registerJs($format, View::POS_HEAD);
echo '<label class="control-label">Provinces</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'state_12',
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('format'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('format'),
        'escapeMarkup' => $escape,
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
```

In this example as you can see, the filename with the image of the state has the same name of the state.id

```
src = '$url' +  state.id.toLowerCase() + '.png'
```

and it's simple to use.

But my problem is that the filename for each state is different and is stored in my db. For example i have:

```
//Active Record
$state->id  //my state id
$state->img // the name of the image i want
```

How can i pass the right image name for each element of the list to the script?

Thank's for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200583/add-images-with-text-in-select2.. this might be help you

Comment: thanks for the help but also in your link there's a solution like
    src = '$url' +  state.id.toLowerCase() + '.png'
and i don't solve my question.